# dplyr mutate-ifelse combination not creating correct conditional variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a conditional variable using mutate in dplyr which doesn't appear to be working for me. Please see example dataframe and combined score variable I attempt to create. Notice that the 3rd observation of the new variable 'combined.score' is not the sum of B, C and D. It appears that only the first observation is calculated and this value is used for each row observation.

What am I missing here? Would like a reason for why this is happening (not so much alternative code or a solution)

```
df <- 
  data.frame(B=c(1,0,0), 
             C=c(3,4,9), 
             D=c(1,1,0))

#A function to calculate stations whether there is a communication or process component or both
df <- df %>%
  mutate(combined.score = ifelse("B" %in% names(.) & "C" %in% names(.) & "D" %in% names(.), B + C + D,
                                 ifelse("B" %in% names(.) & "C" %in% names(.), B + C,
                                        B))) %>%
  mutate(combined.score.correct = B + C + D)
```

Comment: notice that `"B" %in% names(.) & "C" %in% names(.) & "D" %in% names(.)` is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`; `ifelse` is best used for cases of _vectors_ of logical values; what exactly are you trying to test for with this statement?

Comment: notice that `rowSums(df)` gives you exactly what you want as `combined.score`.

Comment: @MichaelChirico the first conditional would return 'TRUE' so I expect that it would calculate 'combined.score' = B + C + D. Much like the 'combined.score.correct' variable. I've used mutate - ifelse statements plenty of times for dataframes without a hitch, why is this situation special?

Comment: @MichaelChirico: 'what exactly are you trying to test for this statement?' The ifelse statement itself is what I'm testing in the statement i.e., if "B", "C" & "D" exists, then calculate B + C + D. It doesn't do that, so why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for `ifelse` says:

> ifelse returns a value with *the same shape as test*

Here `test` is `"B" %in% names(df) & "C" %in% names(df) & "D" %in% names(df)`, which returns a 1-element vector

```
[1] TRUE
```

Therefore, the `ifelse` call returns a 1-element vector with only the first element of `B + C + D`, which is then recycled across the whole vector.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I see now mutate - ifelse combinations work best as a 'classifier' function.

Comment: You can use this useful inline if function instead: 
# lengths don't have to match
iif <- function(q, a, b){
  if (isTRUE(q)){
    return(a)
  } else {
    return(b)
  }
}