# gsub in dplyr mutate ifelse statement returning first item rather than selected items

Tags: r, gsub, dplyr

I want to run a mutate selectively, given a variable input. The mutate needs to then run a gsub on a chr column. For example:

```
thing <- "yes"

starwars %>% mutate(homeworld = 
                    ifelse(thing == "yes", 
                           gsub("oo", "_", homeworld), 
                           homeworld)) %>%
            select(name, homeworld)
```

gsub in the above code appears to perform the substitution on the first item of homeworld and replace all homeworld values with this:

```
   name               homeworld
   <chr>              <chr>    
 1 Luke Skywalker     Tat_ine  
 2 C-3PO              Tat_ine  
 3 R2-D2              Tat_ine  
 4 Darth Vader        Tat_ine
```

When I would expect:

```
   name               homeworld
   <chr>              <chr>    
 1 Luke Skywalker     Tat_ine  
 2 C-3PO              Tat_ine  
 3 R2-D2              Nab_
 4 Darth Vader        Tat_ine
```

This works if I don't include the ifelse statement:

```
starwars %>% mutate(homeworld = gsub("oo", "_", homeworld))
```

Comment: I think your `ifelse()` is returning only the first element(s) of the vector(s) involved. Try `dplyr::case_when()`, which vectorizes conditions for columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `rowwise`

```
thing <- "yes"

starwars %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(homeworld =
           ifelse(thing == "yes",
                  gsub("oo", "_", homeworld),
                  homeworld)) %>%
  select(name, homeworld) %>%
  ungroup()


# A tibble: 87 x 2
   name               homeworld
   <chr>              <chr>    
 1 Luke Skywalker     Tat_ine  
 2 C-3PO              Tat_ine  
 3 R2-D2              Nab_     
 4 Darth Vader        Tat_ine  
 5 Leia Organa        Alderaan 
 6 Owen Lars          Tat_ine  
 7 Beru Whitesun lars Tat_ine
```

Answer (score 2):

### Note

This issue has already been diagnosed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272445).

## Issue

Per the [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse)

> `ifelse()` returns a value with the same shape as `test`.

Since `test` is the (`logical`) scalar `thing == "yes"`

```
thing == "yes"

# [1] TRUE
```

then your `ifelse()` returns only the (`character`) scalar `"Tat_ine"`

```
ifelse(thing == "yes", gsub("oo", "_", starwars$homeworld), starwars$homeworld)

# [1] "Tat_ine"
```

which is recycled as a constant across your entire `homeworld` column.

## Solution

You *could* perform `rowwise()` operations (with `dplyr`) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68317396) by [Yuriy Saraykin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12025483), or you could efficiently vectorize your condition using `dplyr::case_when()`:

```
thing <- "yes"

starwars %>% mutate(homeworld = case_when(thing == "yes" ~ gsub("oo", "_", homeworld),
                                          TRUE ~ homeworld)) %>%
  select(name, homeworld)
```

The results (sampled below) should match your expectation:

```
# A tibble: 87 x 2
   name               homeworld
   <chr>              <chr>    
 1 Luke Skywalker     Tat_ine  
 2 C-3PO              Tat_ine  
 3 R2-D2              Nab_     
 4 Darth Vader        Tat_ine  
 5 Leia Organa        Alderaan 
 6 Owen Lars          Tat_ine  
 7 Beru Whitesun lars Tat_ine  
 8 R5-D4              Tat_ine  
 9 Biggs Darklighter  Tat_ine  
10 Obi-Wan Kenobi     Stewjon  
# ... with 77 more rows
```